# Why check if object is nil

Tags: objective-c

What's the point of the `if statement` in the following code:

```
- (NSArray *)myMethod
{
    NSArray *array = nil;
    if (!array) {
        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects...]
    }
    return array;
}
```

What's the point of the check if we assigned it to `nil` and what's the point of assigning it to `nil` if we didn't put anything inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of working code, you are correct, there is no point in checking for nil here.  You could rewrite this as:

```
- (NSArray *)myMethod
{
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects...]
}
```

It is hard to know without seeing the entire codebase why this is being done.  One possibility is that the original author expected to eventually replace `myMethod` with a call that potentially passed in a non-nil `array` or expected to eventually add more complex logic in the allocation.

The other very real possibility (and the most likely one in my opinion) is that whoever wrote it had an ingrained habit of always checking for nil and just wasn't thinking.  Since this has no effect on the code, no one ever noticed, or could be bothered to fix.

Comment: I will be using it like this: [[myClass sharedInstance] myMehtod]

Comment: Would that still be fine?

Comment: If the local variable was `static` this would also make a bit more sense.